# Sistema 'trava' apos realizar upload de imagem

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

Galera no meu sistema, faço o upload de uma certa imagem, a imagem é salva em um diretório e depois salvo o produto no banco, até ai td certo, o problema é que depois de salvar o produto o sistema trava, no log do servidor nao apresenta erro algum, estou usando o wildfly, se eu clico para chamar outra pagina o servidor gera o log da consulta corretamente porém nao exibe. Como corrigir este problema?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import dao.ProdutoDAO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.el.ELResolver;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.Produto;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import util.UploadArquivo;

/**
 *
 * @author Nicoletti
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProdutoBean implements Serializable {

    protected String id;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Produto prod = new Produto();
    private final ProdutoDAO prodDAO = new ProdutoDAO();

    public void cadastrar() throws IOException {

        if (prod.getIdProduto() != null) {
            prodDAO.atualizar(prod);
        } else {
            FacesContext c = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ELResolver r = c.getApplication().getELResolver();
            EmpresaBean empresaBean = (EmpresaBean) r.getValue(c.getELContext(), null, "empresaBean");
            prod.setEmpresa(empresaBean.getEm());
            Date data = new Date();
            prod.setDataCadastro(data);
            prodDAO.cadastrar(prod);
        }
        this.prod = new Produto();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("listaproduto.xhtml");

    }

    public void limparCampos() {
        this.prod = null;
        this.prod = new Produto();
    }

    public void carregar(Produto p) throws IOException {
        this.prod = p;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("admproduto.xhtml?id="+p.getIdProduto());
}

    public void carregar() {
        if (id != null && prod.getIdProduto() == null) {
            prod = prodDAO.carregar(Long.parseLong(id));
        }
    }

    public Produto getProd() {
        return prod;
    }

    public void setProd(Produto prod) {
        this.prod = prod;
    }

    public List<Produto> listar(String s) {
        List<Produto> results = new ArrayList<>();
        new ProdutoDAO().listar(s).stream().forEach((p) -> {
            results.add(p);
        });
        return results;

    }

    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {

        if (event != null) {
            try {
                Date data = new Date();
                prod.setImagem(data.getTime() + ".png");
                UploadArquivo up = new UploadArquivo();
                up.copyFile(prod.getImagem(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao fazer upload: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ProdutoBean() {
    }

}


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            template="./../template/template.xhtml"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<ui:define name="content">
    <p:panel class="semBorda">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{produtoBean.id}" />
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{produtoBean.carregar}" />
        </f:metadata>
        <h:outputText value="Cadastro de Produto"></h:outputText>
        <p:separator/>
        <h:form>
            <p:messages></p:messages>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <p:outputLabel value="ID: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{produtoBean.prod.idProduto}"></p:outputLabel>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Nome Produto: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.nomeProduto}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Observação Produto: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.obsProduto}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Código de Barras: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.codigoBarra}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Valor Compra: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.vlrCompra}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Valor Venda: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.vlrVenda}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Desconto Produto: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.descontoProduto}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Validade Produto: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:calendar value="#{produtoBean.prod.validadeProduto}"></p:calendar>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Status Web: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{produtoBean.prod.statusWeb}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ativado" itemValue="true"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Desativado" itemValue="false"></f:selectItem>
                    </p:selectOneRadio>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Lote: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.loteProduto}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Estoque Mínimo: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.estoqueMin}"></p:inputText>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Quantidade Estoque: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{produtoBean.prod.quantEstoque}"></p:inputText>

                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Fornecedor: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:selectOneListbox converter="fornecedorConverter" value="#{produtoBean.prod.fornecedor}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{fornecedorBean.lista()}"
                                       var="fornecedor"
                                       itemLabel="#{fornecedor.nome}"
                                       itemValue="#{fornecedor}"
                                       >
                        </f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneListbox>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Formúla:  "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{produtoBean.prod.formula}"></p:inputTextarea>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Laboratório: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:selectOneListbox converter="laboratorioConverter" value="#{produtoBean.prod.laboratorio}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{laboratorioBean.lista()}"
                                       var="laboratorio"
                                       itemLabel="#{laboratorio.nomeLaboratorio}"
                                       itemValue="#{laboratorio}"
                                       >
                        </f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneListbox>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Grupo: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:selectOneListbox converter="grupoConverter" value="#{produtoBean.prod.grupo}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{grupoBean.lista()}"
                                       var="grupo"
                                       itemLabel="#{grupo.nomeGrupo}"
                                       itemValue="#{grupo}"
                                       >
                        </f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneListbox>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Selecione uma imagem: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:fileUpload id="upload" update="imagem"
                                  fileUploadListener="#{produtoBean.upload}" auto="true"></p:fileUpload>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Imagem: "></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:graphicImage cache="false" id="imagem" height="50px" width="50px" value="../imagens/#{produtoBean.prod.imagem}"></p:graphicImage>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{produtoBean.cadastrar}"  value="Gravar" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>

                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</ui:define>
```

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dao;

import com.mchange.v2.lang.StringUtils;
import controller.EmpresaBean;
import java.util.List;
import javax.el.ELResolver;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import model.Produto;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import util.Filtro;
import util.HibernateUtil;

/**
 *
 * @author Nicoletti
 */
public class ProdutoDAO {

private Session sessao;
private Transaction trans;
private List<Produto> list;

public void cadastrar(Produto p) {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    trans = sessao.beginTransaction();
    try {

        sessao.save(p);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao gravar: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {
       HibernateUtil.clearSession();
    }
}

public void atualizar(Produto p) {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    trans = sessao.beginTransaction();
    try {

        sessao.merge(p);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao atualizar: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally {
       HibernateUtil.clearSession();
    }
}

public List<Produto> listar() {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Criteria cri = sessao.createCriteria(Produto.class);
    FacesContext c = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELResolver r = c.getApplication().getELResolver();
    EmpresaBean empresaBean = (EmpresaBean) r.getValue(c.getELContext(), null, "empresaBean");
    cri.add(Restrictions.eq("empresa", empresaBean.getEm()));
    this.list = cri.list();
    return list;
}

public List<Produto> listar(String s) {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Criteria cri = sessao.createCriteria(Produto.class);
    FacesContext c = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELResolver r = c.getApplication().getELResolver();
    EmpresaBean empresaBean = (EmpresaBean) r.getValue(c.getELContext(), null, "empresaBean");
    cri.add(Restrictions.eq("empresa", empresaBean.getEm()));
    cri.addOrder(Order.asc("nomeProduto"));
    cri.add(Restrictions.like("nomeProduto", s + "%"));
    return cri.list();

}

public List<Produto> filtrados(Filtro filtro) {
    try {
        Criteria criteria = criarCriteriaParaFiltro(filtro);

        criteria.setFirstResult(filtro.getPrimeiroRegistro());
        criteria.setMaxResults(filtro.getQuantidadeRegistros());

        if (filtro.isAscendente() && filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao() != null) {
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao()));
        } else if (filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao() != null) {
            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(filtro.getPropriedadeOrdenacao()));
        }
        return criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
       HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }

}

public int quantidadeFiltrados(Filtro filtro) {
    try {
        Criteria criteria = criarCriteriaParaFiltro(filtro);

        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

        return ((Number) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}

private Criteria criarCriteriaParaFiltro(Filtro filtro) {
    try {
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Criteria criteria = sessao.createCriteria(Produto.class);
        FacesContext c = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELResolver r = c.getApplication().getELResolver();
        EmpresaBean empresaBean = (EmpresaBean) r.getValue(c.getELContext(), null, "empresaBean");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("empresa", empresaBean.getEm()));

        if (StringUtils.nonEmptyString(filtro.getDescricao())) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nomeProduto", filtro.getDescricao(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        }
        return criteria;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public Produto carregar(Long i) {
    sessao = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Produto em = (Produto) sessao.load(Produto.class, i);
    return em;
}
}

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class UploadArquivo {

public String getRealPath() {
    FacesContext aFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) aFacesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();

    return context.getRealPath("/");
}

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    try {
        File file = new File(getRealPath() + "\\imagens\\");
        file.mkdirs();
        try (
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(getRealPath()+"\\imagens\\" + fileName))) 
        {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("Arquivo criado.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Quando ele trava? na pagina de cadastro ou quando abre a pagina listaproduto.xhtml?

Comment: Depois de efetuar o cadastro, posso colocar para redirecionar para qualquer pagina que ele vai carregar a pagina normalmente mas depois disso o sistema não navega mais, e no log do servidor mostra que as consultas estao sendo feitas.

Comment: Salvar o produto, sem o upload da imagem, faz o sistema travar? Só para termos certeza que o problema somente ocorre quando o upload da imagem é realizado.

Comment: Desculpem a demora, mas o post foi resolvido, o problema estava que não estava fechando a conexao quando listava os produtos.